# Is it possible to auto-detect "any" type re-casts?

Tags: typescript

In a large project, we may have a few places where the undesired `any` type cast is used, to access undocumented properties in an object.

Does TypeScript provide a configuration setting to aid in refactoring such code out, by detecting where such casting is used, and pointing out all such places?

And if not, then what would be a recommended approach to detecting those issues?

P.S. We already use `strict` rule in our TypeScript project.

Comment: Two things:
1. In tsconfig set --noImplicitAny flag to true
Now you have all places which you need to add `:any` declaration of the type
2. When everything is defined explicitly now you need to just search by `any` :D
2.a Eventually instead of searching you can use linter and rule `no-any` https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/

Comment: @MaciejSikora Thanks! We already use `noImplicitAny`, in fact through `strict` mode. It is pity that `strict` mode isn't strict enough to prevent type re-castings to `any`. Seems like linting `any` out is the only usable approach so far.